# R data.table: find the difference in mean value between two subsets of rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `R` `data.table` with annual values by group and want to find the difference in the mean value between two sub-periods.

MWE:

```
library(data.table)
mydt = data.table(year = rep(2000:2005, each = 2),
                  myvar = 1:12,
                  grouper = rep(c('A', 'B'), times = 6))
```

The following gets the output I want, but I'm sure there must be a more efficient and readable way of achieving the result?

```
mydt[year < 2003, 
     .(early = mean(myvar)),
     by = "grouper"
    ][mydt[year > 2002,
           .(late = mean(myvar)),
           by = "grouper"],
      on = "grouper"
     ][,
       period_diff := late - early
      ][, 
        c("grouper", "period_diff")]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[]` indexing within each `by=` operation:

```
mydt[, .(period_diff = mean(myvar[year > 2002]) - mean(myvar[year < 2003])), by="grouper"]
#   grouper period_diff
#    <char>       <num>
#1:       A           6
#2:       B           6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem:

```
mydt[order(year), mean(myvar), by=.(grouper, year<2003)][, .(period_diff = diff(V1)), by=.(grouper)]

   grouper period_diff
1:       A           6
2:       B           6
```

Comment: Nice alternative! How does one know whether this will yield -6 or +6 in `period_diff`?